# how to convert ^I character

Tags: shell

I have a text file like this:

```
info  Some info here
```

In which when I use cat -A display this:

```
info^I Some info here
```

How do I edit this so I'll get something like this instead:

```
info<space>-<space>Some info here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/\t/ -/' inputfile
```

if that pattern appears multiple times on a line, use the global option:

```
sed 's/\t/ -/g' inputfile
```

if you want to restrict it to certain lines, for example that start with "info":

```
sed '/^info/ s/\t/ -/' inputfile
```

You can use the `-i` option to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\t/ -/' inputfile
```

If you don't do that you can do this equivalent operation

```
sed 's/\t/ -/' inputfile > outputfile && mv outputfile inputfile
```